# On-topic question inappropriately moved to SuperUser

Tags: support, status-completed

User “romkyns” asked an interesting question about the future of professional programming. It has little if anything to do with *users* and most certainly cannot be answered by anyone who is not in the field of programming. The question I’m referring to is:

- [Can the “Documents” standard folder be rescued and how?](https://superuser.com/questions/246232)

It is clearly intended to incite a philosophical debate on the use of the documents folder *by programmers* and possible steps that future software system designers may take to improve the dire situation he describes.

This question is not going to garner any useful, insightful, constructive or interesting discussion on SuperUser.
Can this question please be moved back?

Comment: Thanks to whoever moved it back!

Comment: I see how that got misinterpreted, but it's a pretty good question. Still needs a new title because it sounds a lot more like "How can I recover my documents".

Comment: @Peter: I’m sure he won’t mind if you go in and edit it with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

> philosophical debate on the use of the documents folder by programmers

I'm not quite sure I understand. The use of a *Documents* folder is not limited in scope to Programmers.

I do not see how this question relates to *"the future of professional programming"*. I encourage you to elaborate your question to include more information.

Comment: “The use of a Documents folder is not limited in scope to Programmers.” — I never said it was, nor does the question. Regardless, the question is about how programmers use it *in their programs* (not on their own computers where they are users).

Comment: @Timwi: Is the use of the Documents folder is not in my mind a programmers issue. If you wish to clarify the question to make it *more programmer specific* you can, but I can't imagine it being a terribly interesting question.

Comment: @JoshK I was surprised to see it migrated. It's a programming issue in the sense that for some bizarre reason software developers think it appropriate to use Documents as dumping ground for their application's working files/data. How we can approach reeducating the software dev masses to use more appropriate locations like AppData is definitely a P.SE question, not SU.

Comment: @Anna: That wasn't what I got from the question, perhaps a rewording? I'm unfamiliar with application access on (assuming) Windows. I never noticed a bloated Documents folder.

Comment: @Josh: Please don’t take this the wrong way, but whether you find a question “terribly interesting” or not has no bearing on what site it should be on.

Comment: @JoshK I think with some rewording to clarify meaning the question would fit P.SE.

Comment: @Timwl: And it doesn't, I was saying you could improve it if you were able but I'm apparently not aware that this is a major issue for developers.

Comment: @Anna: Do you have a SU account?

Comment: @JoshK Yeah, with all of 103 rep. I mostly lurk when I remember it exists.

Comment: @Joshk @Anna You may have figured this out already but leave a post in the Teachers Lounge for one of the SU (or other site) mods if you need them to migrate something back.

Comment: @Walter: I just flagged it for a SU mod.

Comment: @Josh - that works too.